# Moving an image with Video Editor expressions frame offset as a constant

Tags: transforms, video-sequence-editor, keyframes, drivers

I want to move a 2D image at a constant speed using the frame count in the video editor.
I also need to subtract the images self height so it starts from the top.
Pseudocode of an expression into the image strips transform y position:

`self.y.location = -(self.imageresolution.y * 0.5) + videoeditorframecount`

Halving down the resolution so it would be at the top because the reference point is the center and adding frame count to represent how far the image has scrolled with time.
Yes this requires variable video lengths with variable image heights.

The most important is constant speed.

Also another thing I need to know is what other internal hidden variables there are available in the expressions line. Or is this a completely wrong angle of approach? In regards of which I thought if there is a method to extrapolate the position based on 2 keyframes on the graph editor.

The entire reason I'm scooting over to video editor is that rendering an image sequence with real lighting takes a long time. I'm hoping it's faster to render a big image and then move it and render in an editor. I'm open to any other options and currently starting with the video editor to see if it's faster in total.